# LINQ - Join two DataTables, multiply 3 columns, and then get grand total sum

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datatable, dataset

I have two DataTables.

I need to join them, multiply three columns and then another three columns, and then get a grand total sum of those two columns.  If it were pure SQL, there would be no group by clause, just the join and the SUM.  Here's what I have so far, but I'm getting "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause" even though I am ending with a select clause (I'm attempting to select my totals in to variables

```
        decimal weight = 0;
        decimal volume = 0;

            var results = from line in xferLinesTable.AsEnumerable()
                          join invmast in inv_mast.AsEnumerable()
                            on line.Field<int>("inv_mast_uid") equals invmast.Field<int>("inv_mast_uid")

                          let extended_weight = line.Field<decimal>("quantity_requested") * line.Field<decimal>("unit_size") * invmast.Field<decimal>("net_weight")
                          let extended_volume = line.Field<decimal>("quantity_requested") * line.Field<decimal>("unit_size") * invmast.Field<decimal>("cube")
                          into lines

                          select weight = lines.Sum(w => w.extended_weight), volume = lines.Sum(v => v.extended_volume);
```

Where am I going wrong?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using an anonymous type.  Something like this:

```
select new {weight = lines.Sum(w => w.extended_weight), volume = lines.Sum(v => v.extended_volume)};
```

Looked a little closer at your code.  You're using the `into` keyword wrong.  It has to be used with a `group`, `join` or `select` clause.  Something like this:

```
var results = (from line in xferLinesTable.AsEnumerable()
              join invmast in inv_mast.AsEnumerable()
              on line.Field<int>("inv_mast_uid") equals invmast.Field<int>("inv_mast_uid")

              let extended_weight = line.Field<decimal>("quantity_requested") * line.Field<decimal>("unit_size") * invmast.Field<decimal>("net_weight")

              let extended_volume = line.Field<decimal>("quantity_requested") * line.Field<decimal>("unit_size") * invmast.Field<decimal>("cube")

              group new {weight = extended_weight,volume = extended_volume} by "A" into lines

              select new {weightTotal = lines.Sum(x => x.weight), volumeTotal = lines.Sum(x => x.volume)}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's what I had originally, but I'm still getting the "query body must end in select statement" error in Visual Studio (the squiggle is on the "into" keyword

If I take out the "into lines" statement, then the "lines" reference in the Select statement become invalid of course...

Comment: @dcaparaso - I looked a little closer at your code and added more for you to look at

Comment: stupid question, how do I then use my resulting weightTotal and volumeTotal in the rest of my code?  eg, assign the results to a variable or cast them as a string for output?

Comment: @dcaparaso - `results` is an anonymous class with 2 fields `weightTotal` and `volumeTotal`.  You can access them like any other class(`results.weightTotal`).

Comment: I must still be missing something..... VS says "'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: decimal weightTotal, decimal volumeTotal>>' does not contain a definition for 'weightTotal' and no extension method 'weightTotal' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable on `var displayweight = results.weightTotal` directly after my query...

Comment: `var results = from line in xferLinesTable.AsEnumerable()
                              join invmast in inv_mast.AsEnumerable()
                              on line.Field<int>("inv_mast_uid") equals invmast.Field<int>("inv_mast_uid")

                              let extended_weight = line.Field<decimal>("quantity_requested") * line.Field<decimal>("unit_size") * invmast.Field<decimal>("net_weight")

                              let extended_volume = line.Field<decimal>("quantity_requested") * line.Field<decimal>("unit_size") * invmast.Field<decimal>("cube")`

Comment: `group new { weight = extended_weight, volume = extended_volume } by "A" into lines

                              select new { weightTotal = lines.Sum(x => x.weight), volumeTotal = lines.Sum(x => x.volume) };

                var displayweight = results.weightTotal;
                var displayVolume = results.volumeTotal;`

Comment: see above, some trouble with the copy and pasting, sorry..TIA

Comment: Sorry I missed adding some of the code.  Group the linq statement in `()`'s and add `.FirstOrDefault()` to the end.  Now result will be what I said earlier.

Comment: thanks, just figured that out, too!!! results.FirstOrDefault().weightTotal;

Answer (score 0):

[Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) might what you need.